# Pandas - Can't cast string to datetime

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, lambda, strftime

I have a datframe that stores some information from text files, this information gives me details about my execution jobs.

I store all this information in a dataframe called "df_tmp". On that dataframe I have a column "end_Date" where I want to store the end date from the file that is the last line of my file but if in the dataframe I don't have any value I want to store the current_time.

Imagine that the information from my file is on the following variable:

```
string_from_my_file = 'Execution time at 2019/10/14 08:06:44'
```

What I need is:

In case of my manual file don't have any date on the last line I want to store the current_time.
For that I am trying with this code:

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df_tmp['end_date'] = df_tmp['end_date'].fillna(current_time).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.to_datetime(re.search("([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})", str(df_tmp['string_from_my_file']))[0]))
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_tmp['end_date'] = df_tmp['end_date'].fillna(current_time).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if not pd.isnull(x) else pd.to_datetime(re.search("([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})", str(df_tmp['string_from_my_file']))[0]))
```

In this part, `lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`, need to change `x` to datetime to apply `strftime()`.

Probable reason for your error:
Even if `end_date` column is of type datetime, but you are filling that column with values having `str` type. This is changing data type of `end_date` column.